# text-based viewer for profiling results

Tags: linux, profiling, terminal

Do you know of a text-based application for viewing results of application profiling? The profiling results basically contain a list of C++ function call backtraces and how often these backtraces were encountered; now I'm looking for a console tool to analyze the raw data (which backtrace occurred most often; which function was called most often, independent of call trace...).

So far I've created callgrind-compatible files from the raw data and then used the excellent KCachegrind tool for analysis; but now I'm also looking for a tool that works without on text-based terminal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`callgrind_annotate`](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html).

> This command reads in the profile data, and prints a sorted lists of functions, optionally with source annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote such a viewer once. It focussed on a line of code, showing the percent of samples running through that line, and a butterfly view allowing transitions to superior or subordinate lines of code.

It made a nice demo, but did I really use it? Not for long.

(I'm assuming the stack samples have been taken during the interval that you wish to speed up, i.e. not during user-wait.)

The thing is, the program is probably doing something wasteful in that time. (If it is not, you can't speed it up.)
Whatever that wasteful thing is, it consists of some percent of time being spent for poor reasons, like 10%, 50%, 90%, or whatever. During that time, it is on the stack, so an examination of the stack samples will show it.

*And, you don't have to look at very many of them. If something is taking 50% of time, 1000 samples will show it on about 500, and 10 samples will show it on about 5. The larger number of samples will estimate the percentage with an extra digit of precision. If your goal is to isolate the problem so you can fix it, you don't need that extra digit.*

So, a tool that shows you, by line, the percent of stack samples going through that line is a very nice thing to have, because the wasteful code will appear on it, showing the percentage.

What it does not show you is the reason why the statement is being executed, which is how you know if it's wasteful. Looking at the statement's context on the stack does tell you that.

So even though I had the viewer, I just ended up examining the samples themselves, and only about 10 or 20 of them. The bigger the percentage is, the smaller the number of samples I need to look at before I find it. [Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295799/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-code/4299378#4299378)